# Need help in framing the set of linear equations for a binary variable as per following conditions

Tags: linear-programming, binary-programming

I have a binary variable array: $Y(i,j)$. Where $i=1,\dots,I$ and $j=1,\dots,K$. Here $K$ and $I$ need not to be same. In other words, the matrix formed $Y(i,j)$ is not necessarily be a squared ( but it can be).

Let us take an example of $Y$ as follows: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

We can see that $I=3$ and $K=12$. Let us assume that $j=1,2$ are from $group \space A$ and $j=3$ is from $group \space B$

**Condition 1:** Only $j=1,5,9,\dots$ positions will have either $0$ or $1$. Rest will only have $0$. **Except for following condition**

**Condition 2:** If $Y(i,j)$ is $1$ for elements in $group \space A$ and $group \space B$ simultaneously, then  $Y(i \in group \space A , group \space B ,j=j+1)$ should also be $1$.

For example:

$Y(1,1)$ and $Y(3,1)$ are $1$. Thus, $Y(1,2)$ and $Y(3,2)$ are also $1$.

**Condition 3:** If multiple $Y(i,j)$ from same groups are $1$ for same $j$, then **Condition 2** does not hold true.

For example,

$Y(1,9)$ and $Y(2,9)$ are $1$. But $Y(1,10)$ and $Y(2,10)$ are NOT $1$.

How to write a set of generic linear equations in terms of :

- Groups : $Group \space A ,Group \space B, \dots$
- $i: 1,\dots,I$
- $j: 1,\dots,K$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to not to take into account the non-$1,5,9,\dots $ positions. I forced them to be $0$ directly. But then the problem is : I cannot modify them later to include condition 2 and 3. I also tried to put the condition like this: $\sum{Y(i)} \le 1$ from $i=1 $to $4$ and then from $i =5 $to $8$ and so on.. but then the non-$1,5,9,\dots $ positions also get ones. Which is troubling me.

Comment: So, for me the real problem is : How to force the positions : $i = {2,3,4}, {6,7,8}....$ to $0$. And also  to get conditions 2 ,3 to be satisfied at the same time.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include what your question is?

Comment: Kindly see the question. I have written it correctly. Thank you for your comment. It was not clear before.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert logical implications to linear constraints somewhat automatically by using conjunctive normal form.  For your first example:
$$
(Y(1,1) \land Y(3,1)) \implies (Y(1,2) \land Y(3,2)) \\
\lnot(Y(1,1) \land Y(3,1)) \lor (Y(1,2) \land Y(3,2)) \\
(\lnot Y(1,1) \lor \lnot Y(3,1)) \lor (Y(1,2) \land Y(3,2)) \\
(\lnot Y(1,1) \lor \lnot Y(3,1) \lor Y(1,2)) \land 
(\lnot Y(1,1) \lor \lnot Y(3,1) \lor Y(3,2)) \\
(1 - Y(1,1) + 1 - Y(3,1) + Y(1,2) \ge 1) \land 
(1 - Y(1,1) + 1 - Y(3,1) + Y(3,2) \ge 1) \\
(Y(1,1) + Y(3,1) - 1 \le Y(1,2)) \land 
(Y(1,1) + Y(3,1) - 1 \le Y(3,2)) \\
$$
We have obtained linear constraints
\begin{align}
Y(1,1) + Y(3,1) - 1 &\le Y(1,2) \tag1 \\ 
Y(1,1) + Y(3,1) - 1 &\le Y(3,2) \tag2 \\
\end{align}
It is easy to check that substituting $Y(1,1) = 1$ and $Y(3,1) = 1$ into $(1)$ and $(2)$ forces $Y(1,2)=1$ and $Y(3,2)=1$, respectively.